# What is the best way to deal with a library that has not marked any functions const?

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to implement the use of a C++ library within my project that has not used const modifiers on its access functions. Up until now I have been using const in all of my code but this new library is causing two main problems:

1. Functions where the arguments are passed as const references cannot use the argument's access functions if these arguments are of a type defined by the library.
2. Classes with member objects of types defined by the library cannot use the access functions of these objects within a const function.

What is the best way to overcome this issue? The easiest solution would be to simply remove all use of const from my code but that would be quite frustrating to do.

**Additional info:** In this case I do have access to the source code and can see that the access functions do not modify anything. I omitted this information as I was interested in the more general case as well. For my scenario, `const_cast` appears to be the way to go

PS The library writer is not evil! It is more a bit of rough and ready code that he has kindly open sourced. I could ditch the library and use something more professional as others have noted. However, for this small time-constrained project, the simplicity of the interface to this library has made it the best choice.

Comment: is it an open source library? if so you could simply fork your own version of it and add constness to it where applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How easy is it to tell whether the functions in the library actually modify anything or not?

If it's easy to tell, and they don't, then you can `const_cast` your const pointer/reference to non-const and call the library function. You might want to throw a wrapper around the library classes to do this for you, which is tedious and verbose but gets that code out of your classes. This wrapper could perhaps be a subclass that adds some const accessors, depending whether the way you use the library class allows that to work.

If it's hard to tell, or they do modify things, then you need to use non-const instances and references to the library classes in your code. `mutable` can help with those of type (2), but for those of type (1) you just need to pass non-const arguments around.

For an example of why it might be hard, consider that the library author might have written something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    size_t times_accessed;
    int value;
    int get() {
        ++times_accessed;
        return value;
    }
};
```

Now, if you `const_cast` a `const` instance of `Foo` and call `get()`, you have undefined behavior[*]. So you *have* to be sure that `get` really doesn't modify the object it's called on. You could mitigate this a bit, by making sure that you never create any const instances of `Foo`, even though you do take const references to non-const instances. That way, when you `const_cast` and call `get` you at least don't cause UB. It might make your code confusing, that fields keep changing on objects that your functions claim not to modify.

[*] Why is it undefined behavior? It has to be, in order that the language can guarantee that the value of a `const` object never changes in a valid program. This guarantee allows the compiler to do useful things. For example it can put `static const` objects in read-only data sections, and it can optimize code using known values. It also means that a `const` integer object with a visible initializer is a compile-time constant, which the standard makes use of to let you use it as the size of an array, or a template argument. If it wasn't UB to modify a const object, then const objects wouldn't be constant, and these things wouldn't be possible:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int a;
    Foo(int a) : a(a) {}
};

void nobody_knows_what_this_does1(const int *p); // defined in another TU
void nobody_knows_what_this_does2(const int *p); // defined in another TU

int main() {
    const Foo f(1);
    Foo g(1);
    nobody_knows_what_this_does1(&f.a);
    nobody_knows_what_this_does2(&g.a);
    int x;
    if (std::cin >> x) {
        std::cout << (x / f.a); // Optimization opportunity!
        std::cout << (x / g.a); // Cannot optimize!
    }
}
```

Because `f` is a const object, and hence `f.a` is a const object, the optimizer knows that `f.a` has value 1 when it's used at the end of the function. It could, if it chose, optimize away the division. It *doesn't* know the same thing about `g.a`: `g` is not a const object, a pointer to it has been passed into unknown code, so its value might have changed. So if you're the author of `nobody_knows_what_this_does1` or `nobody_knows_what_this_does2`, and you're thinking of `const_cast`ing `p` and using it to modify its referand, then you can only do it if you somehow know that the referand is non-const. Which normally you don't, so normally you don't use `const_cast`.

Comment: But why there is _undefined_ behaviour?

Comment: @tonytony : `Foo` is a POD type, so if it is allocated `static` and `const`, it will likely end up in a readonly memory segment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the following options:

1. If you are sure the library is working as it should if it was using the `const` specifier, you could use `const_cast<>` to remove the const-ness of your objects when dealing with the library

   Alternatively, you could make non-const copies of your const objects and pass those to the library, then update the changes to the non-const parts on your original objects
2. Search for another library that is const-correct
3. remove all const from your code (not recommended)

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't consider option #3 a real option.

Comment: @ildjarn - Agreed, but it does provide a solution if all else fails

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to copy your object into a modifiable temp and pitch it.  This is probably the safest thing to do if you're in the circumstance where your class offers a copy constructor and it's not too expensive.  This has been my preferred method when it's available, as I know it's 100% safe.  Silly example:

```
int getInfoFromString(String& str); //what??  why isn't str const :(
```

So I do

```
 String temp(str);
 int stuffINeed = getInfoFromString(temp);
 //happy
```

Comment: Assuming that `String` has the default copy constructor, that takes a const reference. If the author of this evil library has implemented a copy constructor, then that might take a non-const reference too!

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion:  Are you familiar with the `mutable` keyword?  If you use it correctly, it might actually accomplish exactly what you're trying to do, with exactly one word added to your code.  This keyword can evoke religious opinion at the level of `goto` because it's probably used as a kludge for every hundred times that it's used because it really is the best design option.  In your case, it's debatable which it is but I think it fits the spirit:  your annoying library object is something that can be fake-modified without breaking the semantic const-ness of *your* methods, so go ahead.

```
class Outer {
    mutable Inner inner;
    public void foo() const { 
        inner.nonConstMethod(); //compiles because inner is mutable
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If the library's interface is not big, you can create a wrapper, where you would adjust your code to expected types, by either casting or making a copy of parameters, which are passed to library's functions.

But do not degrade your code in order to use the library.